# Rrule Until tag data value

Tags: java, rrule

I'm working on a project which takes rrule to generate next occurrences. But I'm not able to understand what i need to put in UNTIL tag of rrule.

```
String str="RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20190625T000000Z;INTERVAL=2;";
```

Idk how to convert date into `"20190625T000000Z"`.I'm using rfc 2445 java library. If user enters the date as a string  for example :`25/06/2019......`i need to set this value in UNTIL tag as shown above. If I set the default value in UNTIL then it works but not when i make it user friendly.. I'm taking all the values from user as start date, end date, interval, Byday,Until... But idk what value to set in UNTIL. 
If someone can help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This Question is not entirely clear. I suggest you take a bit more time and effort in phrasing and writing your question. Also, this is not a casual chat site, this is meant to be more like Wikipedia, a repository of knowledge in Q&A form. So, please, no “idk”. Take time to write properly with full spelling, capitalization, and punctuation.

Comment: And please learn about formatting code with Stack Overflow’s edition of Markdown. It is rather simple, four leading SPACE characters or back-tick (GRAVE ACCENT) marks surrounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Parsing basic ISO 8601 format

Your input `20190625T000000Z` is the “basic” variation of standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format to represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The word “basic” means minimizing the use of delimiters (I do not recommend this, as it makes the string less readable by humans).

Defining a formatting pattern to match input.

```
String input = "20190625T000000Z";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println("odt.toString(): " + odt);
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/c3aXUI).

> odt.toString(): 2019-06-25T00:00Z

## Translating date to moment

> If user enters the date as a string for example :25/06/2019......i need to set this value in UNTIL tag as shown above

First, parse that input string into a `LocalDate`, representing a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter fDateOnly = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "25/06/2019" , fDateOnly );
```

> ld.toString(): 2019-06-25

As for translating that date into a moment (a date with time-of-day in a zone or offset-from-UTC), that is trickier than it sounds intuitively.

A date such as the 25th of June 2019 represents an entire day. And a theoretical date at that. The moments when a day begins and ends varies around the globe by time zone. A new day begins much earlier in Tokyo Japan than in Paris France, and even later in Montréal Québec.

Another issue is that the day does not always begin at 00:00:00. Because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), the first moment of a day on some dates in some zones may be something like 01:00:00. Let the *java.time* classes determine first moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-06-25T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

That [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object represents a specific moment. But it uses the wall-clock time adopted by the people of a particular region (a time zone). Your goal is a moment in UTC. Fortunately, we can adjust from the zone to UTC by converting to an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) (a date and time with a context of offset-from-UTC rather than a time zone). We can specify UTC (an offset of zero) by the [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) constant.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

> odt.toString(): 2019-06-24T23:00Z

Note how 00:00 on the 25th in Tunisia is 11 PM “yesterday” the 24th in UTC. Same moment, same simultaneous point on the timeline, but two different wall-clock times.

Lastly, we need a string in that “basic” ISO 8601 format. Use the same formatter we defined above.

```
DateTimeFormatter fIso8601DateTimeBasic = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" );
String output = odt.format( fIso8601DateTimeBasic );
```

> output: 20190624T230000Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WpImgI).

Just what is the difference between a time zone and an offset-from-UTC? An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Nothing more, nothing less, just a number (well, three numbers). A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. For example, in most of North America, the offset changes twice a year, springing ahead an hour and then falling back an hour (the lunacy of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)).

Tip: Date-time handling is surprisingly tricky and slippery. If you are working with calendars and the [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) spec for data exchange, I suggest you take a long while to study the concepts and practice with the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: That solution is helpful but I can't use LocalDate class to parse the date. Can I use Date class instead?

Comment: No, `Date` is not for dates, it is for moments in UTC. And `Date` is another terrible legacy class, supplanted by `java.time.Instant`. The `LocalDate` class is built into Java. You can use it, just use `import java.time.* ;`

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks for the help.